# Json Array in tableview

Tags: ios, json

I want to ask if i have 5 json url link,
like this:

```
`"www.testing.com/apps/star_json.php?code=1"`

`"www.testing.com/apps/star_json.php?code=2"`

`"www.testing.com/apps/star_json.php?code=3"`

`"www.testing.com/apps/star_json.php?code=4"`

`"www.testing.com/apps/star_json.php?code=5"`
```

how can i fixed `"www.testing.com/apps/star_json.php"` this path and only write a different code in my different getDataURL?

Comment: Sorry, bro, but no one will ever understand what you are talking about. You provided absolutely **no** background information. Also we don't know what you want to achieve, what you already tried to do and what your problem is. SO is not a »How do I create an application« forum.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mean how to concat strings?

```
for each code
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.testing.com/apps/star_json.php?code=%d", code]`
```

But this is an embarassingly badly posed question :D

Comment: Yes,that what I want,haha,sorry for my bad question